# Changing a property of an element in a list doesn't change it

Tags: c#

I'm totally confused about a value not being stored. There's an instance of a class that has a member defined like this.

```
public class MyHolder
{
    public List<MyPart> Parts { get; set; }
}

public class MyPart
{ 
    public bool Taken { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I try to probe that class for IDs to accepted elements and it doesn't work because the updates I'm making don't seem to get through. So I've created the following, extremely simple probe.

```
List<int> before = myHolder.Where(e => e.Taken).Select(f => f.Id).ToList();
myHolder.First(p => p.Id == 7).Taken = false;
List<int> before = myHolder.Where(e => e.Taken).Select(f => f.Id).ToList();
```

To my great surprise, the number of `before` and `after` stays the same! I've verified that for **all** the IDs and I've made sure that e.g. 7 is `true` from the start. I even tried initiating it with `false` and then setting it to `true`. There's no other logic going on, as far I can see. I know for sure that it's **me** doing something wrong but I'm not sure what it is. And it's kind of hard to search for it because this weird behavior is very generic.

It's not like we create a copy of `myHolder` and put the updated value in it. And if it's so, how can I obtain and write to **the real thing**?

I'm hoping that someone sees something obvious. Or at least points me in a good direction to search more.

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Your current code wouldn't even compile (you've got `before` twice, and there's no `after`).

Comment: and you have `myHolder.Where`.. perhaps you mean `myHolder.Parts.Where` ? and also there is no `Id` property in the code.

Comment: @Selman22 I was trying out if I changed `int Id` to `string Name` but that gave no difference,. I'll update the question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean something like this:

```
public class MyHolder
{
    public List<MyPart> Parts { get; set; }
}

public class MyPart
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Taken { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In this code update works as expected

```
var myHolder = new MyHolder {
    Parts = new List<MyPart> {
        new MyPart { Id = 7, Taken = true, Name = "Test" },
        new MyPart { Id = 8, Taken = false, Name = "Test 1" }
    }
};

var before = myHolder.Parts.Where(e => e.Taken).Select(f => f.Id).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(before.Count());

myHolder.Parts.First(p => p.Id == 7).Taken = false;

var after = myHolder.Parts.Where(e => e.Taken).Select(f => f.Id).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(after.Count());
```

See working [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xXalmd)

Comment: I got it. It was pure confusion. Even if I cast to `List<T>`, the contents still came from an enumerable. And that was loaded from the DB. Once I went  list-way all the way, it actually behaved as I expected. +1 for nice example. I needed a sanity check from others, that's all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -

```
public class MyHolder
{
    public List<MyPart> Parts { get; set; }
}

public class MyPart
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Taken { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}



var holder = new MyHolder() { Parts = new List<MyPart>() { new MyPart() { Id = 7, Name = "R", Taken = true }, new MyPart() { Id = 8, Name = "S", Taken = true }, new MyPart() { Id = 9, Name = "T", Taken = true } } };

List<int> before = holder.Parts.Where(m => m.Taken).Select(f => f.Id).ToList();
holder.Parts.First(p => p.Id == 7).Taken = false;
List<int> after = holder.Parts.Where(m => m.Taken).Select(f => f.Id).ToList();
```